# Can we use Domain model written in Scala in a Java/Spring Application?

Tags: java, scala, spring-boot, domain-driven-design, domain-model

Is there a way to use a Domain Model written in Scala from a Spring+Java+Maven project ?

Asking this after going through Scott Wlaschin's [video](https://youtu.be/PLFl95c-IiU) on Functional Domain Modelling. Would love to implement some of it using Scala and bring the power of Functional DDD to our mundane old spring code!

Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "ADT magic" in the video. There is a powerful type system in the language and a functional approach.

You can leverage Java's type system to some degree and also use some functional libraries like [vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) or maybe something like [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/). It will improve your code greatly, but it wouldn't be so powerful like in functional languages with great type system (like F#, Haskell, Scala, and other ML-like langs)

If you want to leverage Scala's type system (which is even more powerful then F#) you should use Scala almost everywhere because guarantees of the type system are in the compiler. And you can use Spring from Scala (but I think this is a huge antipattern).

Comment: The sum types, product types being used in the video to create the powerful type system do not classify as ADT ?

Comment: @Somjit yes, it is ADT. But it does not create "powerful type system", it uses the type system to enforce some domain logic at compile time and to bring domain logic in application design.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts here.
One part has nothing to do with ADT's, rather Scala and Java compatibility.
Everything written in scala compiles down to JVM bytecode, so whatever 'magic' you are referring to, can be written in Java, albeit much less concise and readable.
And therefore is usable.
The second part is the type-checker
Part of ADT magic is compile-time safety checks, such as exhaustive match checks amongst others...
You will not get that when you call `instanceof` in java on a case class designed in Scala

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but isn't the sum types or product types used to create the powerful type system are ADT themselves?

Comment: "whatever 'magic' you are referring to, can be written in Java" - you are wrong. magic happens in compile time, you can't have the same guarantees in Java as you can have in Scala.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov you didnt read my answer to completion.I explicitly address, that as part of compiler checks. I separated out the code that is running (which is plain old bytecode) from the compiler type checker ,as 2 entities to think about.